# SQL aggregate data based on a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have to aggregate data in my SQL query (DISTINCT) based on a single column in this kind of fashion:

original table:

```
id|var_val|id_res_id|var_id_id|device_id|var_val_conv
11|126    |3864     |36       |abc123   |1.21
10|136    |3764     |36       |abc123   |1.51
9 |115    |3582     |35       |abc123   |4.41
8 |143    |2464     |36       |abc123   |8.81
7 |226    |1844     |35       |abc123   |9.21
6 |12     |3364     |34       |abc123   |11.7
```

so i would to aggregate data based on column var_id_id having just first data fo every different values of var_id_id as in example:

result:

```
id|var_val|id_res_id|var_id_id|device_id|var_val_conv
11|126    |3864     |36       |abc123   |1.21
9 |115    |3582     |35       |abc123   |4.41
6 |12     |3364     |34       |abc123   |11.7
```

i try this query but i don't get what i would:

```
SELECT VR.id, var_val, id_res_id, var_id_id, AR.device_id, var_val_conv
    FROM public.api_site_varsresults as VR,
    public.modbus_modbusvariable as MV,
    public.api_site_results as AR
    WHERE VR.var_id_id = MV.id AND VR.id_res_id = AR.id
    AND AR.device_id = 'abc123'
    GROUP BY VR.id, var_id_id, AR.device_id
    ORDER BY VR.id DESC;
```

How can i group for var_id_id having just first line encountred for every result?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use window function `first_value` in next way:

```
WITH ids AS (SELECT DISTINCT
    first_value(id) over (partition by var_id_id order by id desc) id
FROM api_site_results as VR
) SELECT * FROM ids JOIN api_site_results USING(id);
```

[PostgreSQL window functions online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=ec2241345e5c3b74ab6d824544cd6e23&php_version=null&sql_version=psql14)

**Result:**

```
+====+=========+===========+===========+===========+==============+
| id | var_val | id_res_id | var_id_id | device_id | var_val_conv |
+====+=========+===========+===========+===========+==============+
| 11 | 126     | 3864      | 36        | abc123    | 1.21         |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 9  | 115     | 3582      | 35        | abc123    | 4.41         |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 6  | 12      | 3364      | 34        | abc123    | 11.7         |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks salva, i try WITH ids AS (SELECT DISTINCT
    first_value(id) over (partition by var_id_id order by id desc) id
FROM api_site_varsresults as VR
) SELECT * FROM ids JOIN api_site_results USING(id); but i had no record as result

Answer (score 0):

The "distinct on" from postresql will do that

```
select distinct on(var_id_id) t.*
  from api_site_results t 
  order by var_id_id;
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/3074)